# Is there any way to include device identifier in firebase performance monitor?

Tags: android, ios, firebase-performance

Firebase Performance is a great tool to monitor custom traces and network requests. I have multiple devices with same device model, Is there any way to set identification by passing UDID or any unique identification on device level?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to add custom data (like UDID) to traces.

Comment: An update to this. As of 11.8.0 (Android) and 4.8.0 (iOS), Firebase Performance now allows you to set custom attributes on traces. https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom-attributes